# What Charset to use for Languages

Tags: mysql

SO I'm in the process of creating a database for a website that will store info in multiple languages.  I understand that there are "Charsets" in MySql that determine which types of characters can be stored in a table.  Should I be concerned about what type of charset to use when I create my database in order to be able to store the maximum amount of different characters for different languages?  Should text dump backups be an issue with any particular charset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 can store pretty much any human language in use.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8. It's the industry default, especially on the Internet as the IETF generally recommends it. It's also the default encoding for most international stuff on Unix as well (which is where MySQL runs 95% of the time). Windows uses UTF-16 I believe.

Most programming languages and libraries have support for UTF-8 as well.

In general you should always use UTF-8 for everything unless you have a reason not to.